# Como crear dos sesiones independientes para cada subdominio

Tags: php

Estimados tengo el siguiente inconveniente, resulta ser que estoy trabajando con subdominios en mi sitio web llamado **ecuservicechile.lc** , voy a trabajar con dos subdominios **portal.ecuservicechile.lc** donde se logean todos los usuarios y **admin.ecuservicechile.lc** donde solo tiene acceso el administrador del sitio. Cada subdominio tiene su propia base de datos.

Cuando un usuario es logeado exitosamente en el portal, creo las sesiones de la siguiente manera redirigiendo al sitio correspondiente en el portal, tambien utilizo las mismas lineas de codigo (pero en otro script), cuando se logea el administrador en admin. Resulta ser que si me logeo con algún usuario de prueba en portal, y luego ingreso al subdominio admin, tambien figuro logeado, ya que existe la misma variable $_SESSION['correo'];, como puedo hacer que ambas sessiones sean independientes ? o solo deberia cambiar los nombres de las variables de sesion en el otro script ?

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['fecha'] = date("Y-m-d G:i:s");
$_SESSION['correo'] = $fila['correo'];
$_SESSION['nombre'] = $fila['nombre'];
$_SESSION['apellido'] = $fila['apellido'];
$_SESSION['idusuario'] = $fila['idusuario'];
$_SESSION['sesion-start'] = time();
$_SESSION['sesion-expire'] = $_SESSION['sesion-start'] + (15 * 60); 
header("location: ".RUTA_SUBDOMINIO."ordenes");
```

También mencionar que tengo lo siguiente en el htaccess que se encuentra en la raiz de la web.

```
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    SetEnvIf Origin "http(s)?://(www\.)?(portal.ecuservicechile.lc|admin.ecuservicechile.lc)$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
</IfModule>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,PUT,POST,DELETE
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
php_value session.cookie_domain ".ecuservicechile.lc"
```

Me gustaría que no ocurra ese problema de las sesiones, ya que cuando la web este en el servidor real, podria ocasionar problemas de seguridad.

Comment: Puedes hacer una validación extra utilizando tokens, más concretameme Json Web Token para verificar eso, además investiga sobre la autenticación por roles

Comment: Es que en teoria no son roles de usuario, ya que en el subdominio portal se registran los usuarios y realizan acciones como pagar con tarjetas de credito, generar ordenes de servicio,etc. En el Subdominio admin es solo para administrar la web a nivel html, osea añadir nuevos servicios, algun banner nuevo, cambiar precios y cosas asi, entonces son sitios completamente distintos.

Comment: Te has planteado usar docker para tener tus subdominios independientes? Se que esta respuesta no tiene nada que ver con php, pero este tipo de problemas te los puedes ahorrar, es más podrías tener cada subdominio con una versión diferente de php, incluso en una de las dos no tener php, etc

Answer (score 2):

Sin tener que hacer modificaciones del archivo `php.ini`, ni a variables en tiempo de ejecución, puedes darle [nombre a cada sesión](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.session-name.php), es el método que uso para tener múltiples sesiones (1 por cada sitio) en *localhost*.

Para el sitio principal:

```
<?php
session_name('principal');
session_start();
```

Para el subdominio:

```
<?php
session_name('sub-dominio');
session_start();
```

De esta forma, las sesiones son completamente independientes.

Comment: Excelente solución, duda: ¿Cómo recuperas las variables con el mismo nombre pero sesiones con nombre distinto? Es decir ¿cómo especificas que quieres leer la variable A de la sesión X y no la variable A de la sesión Y?

Comment: @AlejandroRivas, son independientes, solo puedes acceder a las variables de sesión creadas para el nombre que especificaste al iniciar el script.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar la configuración del init, y puedes modificarla desde el servicio donde estas inicializando las variables para los admins:

```
<?php
  If ($_POST["usr"] == "admin"){ 
    ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'admin.ecuservicechile.lc' );
    $ruta = "mi.ruta.html"
  } else {
    ini_set('session.cookie_domain', 'portal.ecuservicechile.lc' );
    $ruta = "mi.ruta2.html"
  }
  session_start();
```

Además tendrás que modificar la redirección...

```
header("location: ". $ruta ."ordenes");
```

Elimina la línea...

```
php_value session.cookie_domain ".ecuservicechile.lc"
```

**POSIBLES PROBLEMAS**

Existe la posibilidad, si tienes un servicio de hosting, de que no te permitan modificar los valores del php.ini (aun en código). Bajo la premisa anterior puedes intentar hablar con el proveedor o hacer dos servicios distintos.

Comment: Si pongo esa linea de codigo antes del session_start() en mi archivo login.php; ya no me deja iniciar sesion

Comment: ¿Cómo admin o como usuario? ¿O en los dos casos? Deberías tener un if para diferenciarlos o tener dos servicios

Comment: En el subdominio admin solo existe un usuario que es el administrador global de la pagina web, quien cambia los precios, las descripciones, todo lo relacionado a la administracion, no hay mas usuarios ni se permite el registro de mas, por lo tanto no hay roles. En el subdominio portal estan los usuarios comunes, tampoco existen roles, ya que es un subdominio con su propia base de datos

Comment: De acuerdo, pero intentaste logearte con la cuenta de usuario o con la cuenta del admin?

Comment: En admin me intento logear con la cuenta de admin, aunque intentara logearme con la de algún usuario me daría error de contraseña o usuario invalido, ya que estan en bases de datos separadas